# Html.LabelFor statement not displaying as assigned value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-helpers

I'm displaying a GuarantorName inside a foreach statement via an Html.LabelFor helper.

However, I'm not getting the expected result.

Instead of displaying the actual value of the GuarantorName, it's simply printing like this:
The Label value says the actual field name which is : GuarantorName, whereas I need the actual value of the name for that field (like "Bill Yeager") which I have verified during debugging has various different first names.

During debugging, I can see in my list that I have actual first names in the collection.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is my view in the Code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Guarantors)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isChecked)
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.GuarantorName)
                    </td>
                }
```

If I try this, I get the following error :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorFirstName + item.GuarantorLastName)
```

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

```
Source Error:


Line 95:                     <td>
Line 96:                         @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isChecked)
Line 97:                         @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorFirstName + item.GuarantorLastName)
Line 98:                     </td>
Line 99:                 }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

LabelFor displays the property name.  You want DisplayFor to show the value of the field.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Guarantors)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorName)
                    </td>
                }
```

Comment: How about if I want to combine the first & last name??? I want to get rid of the space in between the names....

I have the following code, but it's producing the below output:
Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorFirstName) " " @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorLastName)
Mark " " Eid

Comment: um, get rid of " " maybe?  Not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: I simply want a space in betwen the first and last names.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Maybe add &nbsp between the two, where you currently have " ".  eg. Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorFirstName) &nbsp @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorLastName)

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Guarantors)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorName)
                    </td>
                }


And also we can use when used IList<Model>

@for(int i=0;i<model.Guarantors.count();i++)
{
 <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model =>model[i].isChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].GuarantorName)
                    </td>
}
```